# RDP Colour Artifacts/Pixelation

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, colors

I'm connecting with RDP from a Windows 10 laptop using an 8-bit screen to a 10-bit enabled desktop (1 screen has 10bit colour). Once connected, I'm seeing the below.

[image: RDP Colour Issue]

When I physically disconnect the 10-bit enabled monitor, the RDP colour issues disappear. I would prefer not to do this if possible. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance.